# RHEL 8 systemctl startup script fails

Tags: linux, redhat, systemctl

I have an application startup script that works correctly under RHEL 7, using both the "service" and "systemctl" commands.  However when I use the same startup script and service config file on RHEL 8, the "service" command will stop and start the application, but the "systemctl" command will not start it.

The contents of the alm.service file are:

```
[Unit]
Description=Application Lifecycle Management (ALM)
Documentation=https://software.microfocus.com/en-us/solutions/software-development-lifecycle
After=opt-repository.mount

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/opt/HP/ALM/runtime/MFALM.pid
User=alm
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/alm start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/alm stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The portion of the /etc/init.d/alm script that starts the application is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# chkconfig: 35 20 80
# Description: QC Application LifeCycle Management
#

export LANG="en_US.utf8"

source /etc/profile

start () {
echo -n "Starting  HP ALM: "

#Log as alm if account is not the good one
testfile=/opt/repository/base_install/.test_$RANDOM_`date|sed 's/ //g'`
testcmd="touch $testfile"
rmcmd="rm $testfile"
if [ `id -u` -eq 0 ]; then
  testcmd="su alm -c \"touch $testfile\""
  rmcmd="su alm -c \"rm $testfile\""
fi
echo
eval "$testcmd" 2>/dev/null
if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo $'\n'"$0 ERROR: UNABLE to access  REPOSITORY (touch $testfile) on read-write mode !"
  echo $'\n'"!!! ABORTING ALM restart !!!"
  echo $'\n'"But this could also be caused by this  `uname -n`  client needing reboot due to NFS hang."
else
  eval "$rmcmd"
  cd /var/opt/HP/ALM/wrapper
    id
    ls -l HPALM
    #    ./HPALM start
    /var/opt/HP/ALM/wrapper/HPALM start
    echo "HPALM returned Status: " $?
    ls -l /var/opt/HP/ALM/runtime/MFALM.pid
fi
}
```

The HPALM script forks the daemon process and creates the `/var/opt/HP/ALM/runtime/MFALM.pid` file when the process is started.

When I do `service alm start` the application starts correctly.

However, when I do `systemctl start alm` I get the following error in `journalctl -xe`

```
Oct 03 21:18:29 12ee04f4556c44c alm[1311785]: Starting  QC ALM:
Oct 03 21:18:29 12ee04f4556c44c alm[1311785]: user ID  uid=(alm) gid=(team_alm_L4_users) 
Oct 03 21:18:29 12ee04f4556c44c alm[1311785]: calling ./HPALM start
Oct 03 21:18:29 12ee04f4556c44c alm[1311829]: uid=(alm) gid=(team_alm_L4_users)
Oct 03 21:18:29 12ee04f4556c44c alm[1311830]: -rwxr-xr-x. 1 alm team_alm_L4_users 54983 Oct  3 21:06 HPALM
Oct 03 21:18:29 12ee04f4556c44c alm[1311831]: /etc/init.d/alm: line 36: /var/opt/HP/ALM/wrapper/HPALM: Permission denied
Oct 03 21:18:29 12ee04f4556c44c alm[1311785]: HPALM returned Status:  126
Oct 03 21:18:29 12ee04f4556c44c alm[1311832]: ls: cannot access '/var/opt/HP/ALM/runtime/MFALM.pid': No such file or directory
```

The RHEL 8 release version is `Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)`

These same files and scripts work correctly on RHEL 7.

Does anyone know what has changed with RHEL 8 that would cause this to fail with `systemctl` but allow it to work with `service`?

Comment: Is it possible they have enabled SELinux?  Try `getenforce` and see if it is enabled.  For most users, SELinux is more trouble than its worth and can be disabled.  https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-redhat-how-to-set-selinux-modes/

Comment: SELinux is enabled on both the RHEL 7 and RHEL 8 servers.  It appears that a policy change has been made in RHEL 8 that does not allow a process started by systemctl to fork child processes.  If I turn off SELinux on RHEL 8 it will work, but then I lose the other protections of SELinux.
I'm looking at the SELinux documents to try and figure out a way to keep SELinux and allow the application startup script to fork the processes that it needs.

Comment: After talking with our security team, we have decided to set the policy to "permissive" permanently.  After rebooting, the application came up automatically as expected.  Thank you